# multi datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, web, calendar, datepicker

I'm a newbie here, and I'm developing a webApp at the moment.
I'd like to have a multi datepicker feature on my app.

I've searched several multi datepicker plugins, and I guess [this one](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/) is the best because the features on it meet my requirements, but now I'm having difficulty implementing it on my app.

Can someone please give me an example of how it is implemented? I'd like to use the from input style there.

Comment: The page you  pointed to has demos. What else do you want?

Comment: cause i've tried it, but it doesn't work. it drives me confuse. here's the page i try to implement it : dropbox.com/s/t4gpoysyq2hg9lt/a.htm really need help

Answer (score 2):

Follow this steps to implement it

1) Download fullpakage of multidatepicker 
2) link javascript to your page according to below

```
<!-- loads jquery and jquery ui -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
```

3) Load multidatepicker

```
<!-- loads mdp -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
```

4) Link stylesheets

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mdp.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/prettify.css">
```

5) Link other needed JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lang-css.js"></script>
```

6) your input tag

```
<input type="text" value="" id="from-input" class="">
```

7) javascirpt

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#from-input').multiDatesPicker();
</script>
```

There are several options you can add as per your requirement in **MDP**

Comment: it still doesn't work. i've tried it. where should i put the 7th step?
here's the page i try to implement it : https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4gpoysyq2hg9lt/a.htm

really need help

Comment: everything is perfect just  change your input box like this <input type="text" value="" id="from-input" class=""> have edited my answer also

Comment: it works ! thanks,bro. thanks for helping a newbie like me :)